# Filtering SQS queues based on tags in boto3

Tags: python, filter, tags, boto3, amazon-sqs

I have the code to filter the SQS queues based on the queue name prefix. But, now I want to filter the queues based on tags instead of "queue name prefix". Is there a way to do it in boto3?

Here is the code to filter the sqs queues based on their name prefix. This code returns all the SQS queues in my account that starts with the name "Queue"

```
import boto3
sqs = boto3.client('sqs')

response = sqs.list_queues(QueueNamePrefix = 'Queue')
queue_array = response["QueueUrls"]
print(queue_array)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used resource groups instead of directly using queues to filter them based on tags. It is easier this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the tags for each queue that was returned and build a new list based on whether the tags match.

```
queues = [] 
tag_filter = {
    "search_tag_1": "search_value_1",
    "search_tag_2": "search_value_2",
}
for queue_url in sqs.list_queues(QueueNamePrefix="Queues")["QueueUrls"]:
    tag_response = sqs.list_queue_tags(QueueUrl=queue_url)

    if "Tags" in tag_response:
        all_tags_match = True

        for key, value in tag_filter.items():
            if tag_response["Tags"].get(key) != value:
                all_tags_match = False
                break

        if all_tags_match:
            queues.append(queue_url)
```